# How to convert Json to XML in Scala?

Tags: json, xml, scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to convert JSON value:

```
[
    {
        "msg": "Hiiiiii",
        "name": "Ruchirrrr"
    },
    {
        "msg": "Holaaa Amigo",
        "name": "Pablo"
    },
    {
        "msg": "Demo",
        "name": "RuchirD"
    }
]
```

into XML format in Scala.
I am getting above data in json format from MongoDB which is of type **Greeting** object:
*Greeting.scala :*

```
case class Greeting(msg:String,name:String)
```

My route to convert into XML looks like this:

```
path("getXML"){
    val greetingSeqFuture: Future[Seq[Greeting]] = MongoDAL.fetchAllGreetings()
    val jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper
    val greet = jsonMapper.readValue(greetingSeqFuture,classOf[Greeting])
       }
```

***fetchAllGreetings()*** method returns data from my MongoDB database in the form of JSON and here I am trying to convert it into XML. I am also getting error for **readValue()** method.

I have imported `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.4.0"` this dependency in my built.sbt file.

There are many resources to do the same in Java but they wont work for me in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to run an XSLT 3.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <greetings>
    <xsl:for-each select="parse-json($input)?*">
      <greeting msg="{?msg}" name="{?name}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </greetings>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: How shall I use it in akka, so that I get output in the form of XML

Comment: I don't know what "akka" is, but you can use the Saxon XSLT 3.0 processor from Scala via its Java APIs.